# Processing can't find Arduino?

Tags: arduino, processing, firmata

I'm using the Arduino library in [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29). But none of the example [sketches](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) are working. I've tried changing the serial port using `Arduino.list[0]` and `Arduino.list[1]`.
If I choose any higher number it throws an error, so I assume it only sees two serial devices.

My Arduino is connected and working. I have no problem using it through the Arduino application.

What are some other possible problems?

There is an example sketch on page *[Arduino and Processing](http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/processing)* that I have been using to troubleshoot.

Comment: 57600 is the baudrate, not the port number.  You'll need to explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: what os are you using ?

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant I did some more investigation and rewrote my question.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I'm running OSX 10.8, and the newest stable release (1.5 I think) of Processing

Answer (score 1):

This page was a big help: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Serial_Issues

Ultimately, using

```
print(Serial.list()[0]);
```

and trying numbers until the name of the serial port matched what the Arduino IDE was successfully uploading to was the ticket.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the Arduino board's name in Terminal if you do `ls /dev/tty.*`. Try to do the `ls` command before and after plugging in the board to see the effect.

Usually on Macs, it starts with `tty.usbmodem` and something else, while on a PC it is COM3, COM4, etc. so you could do something like:

```
void setup(){
    String[] arduinoList = Arduino.list();
    for (int n=0;n<arduinoList.length && arduino==null;++n) {
        if (arduinoList[n].startsWith("/dev/tty.usbmodem")) {
            println("Arduino found at: " + Arduino.list()[n]);
            arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[n], 57600);
        }
    }
}
```